# SQL Need to retrieve rows from a table "either but not both"

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have a table of users and cities, and need to retrieve rows for users in one city or the other, but not both.

> User      City
>
> -----    -----
>
> Bob      Chicago
>
> Bob      Los Angeles
>
> Charlie  Chicago
>
> Doug     Los Angeles
>
> Ernie    Low Angeles
>
> Frank    Chicago
>
> Frank    Los Angeles

Since Bob and Frank are in both cities, I would expect my result set to be:

```
Charlie  Chicago  
Doug     Los Angeles  
Ernie    Los Angeles
```

It's like a "NOT EXISTS" INNER JOIN but I just can't grasp the SQL Syntax (Oracle SQL). Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from tbl
where "user" in
(select "user" from tbl
 group by "user"
 having count(city) = 1);
```

We just use a subquery that groups the data by user name and filters out only those user names which appear once. Note that `user` is a reserved word, so you would be better off changing the column name to  something like `username`.